# Recently hired, but employer stopped responding after sending in my private data

Tags: new-hires

I recently just got a hired at a job and the hiring manager asked me to send her my social and a picture with my ID. I sent her the requested information.

I messaged her a couple days later and she still hasn't answered so I just called the store and another manager answered and said he would ask and let her know to call me. I have heard nothing since. Should I still message her or just leave it?

Comment: Is it a reputable, well-known, or reliable company in your location ? Did they send you an official job offer yet ? Do you have a start date ?

Comment: "social" as in social security number?! I read it as social media at first. Sign up for identify theft protection as quickly as you can. You've been scammed.

Comment: Can you physically go to the store and ask? You can say you're keen to start and wanted to check the journey time.

Comment: It still doesn't add up. If they were hired in person, then why wasn't the ID info taken in person? This is standard onboarding and there's no reason why this is done like this.

Comment: @Nelson: I'm guessing small business, less than perfectly organized, "hired in person" doesn't necessarily mean "on the spot/on the day of visit"... I don't see a red flag in what we've been given. There may be one in what's been left out

Comment: OP, you need to visit the web sites of Transunion, Experian and Equifax, check your credit reports for new accounts, and then freeze your account NOW NOW NOW if you have given out your SSN.  Don't wait, because scammers won't!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> the hiring manager asked me to send her my social and a picture with my id

I work in cybersecurity.

How sure are you that the hiring manager you talked to was legitimate and not a scam artist phishing for personal information with possible criminal intent? **You should never send SSN or any other PII over a insecure channel such as email**

Comment: 100% this was a scam. I'm guessing when OP "called the store", they either called a fake number given to them by the person who "hired" them, or the person at the store just assumed someone by the name of the hiring manager worked there and agreed to pass the message on.

Comment: @JackGifford: It's *possible* this is just extremely poor security practice on the part of the store. They do need that information for I-9 verification, and if they're incompetent, they might ask for it over instant messaging instead of using a more secure method (such as "do it in person on your first day"). They should not be doing that, of course, but a lot of small businesses are surprisingly bad at basic day to day operations

Comment: you see I did call again but yet no answer and I also left a message im starting to think they are just ignoring me , also I wanted to add I got hired in person and she said she had to send my social to make sure I was okay and that I would start Thursday that's when I messaged but yet no answer I just wanted to know why its hard for managers to say they hired someone else

Comment: If they have actually hired someone else instead, they have no reason to keep you hanging. You will find out for sure on Thursday. Relax and enjoy your last week of "vacation."

Comment: @anthony - Do you mean "any" email is considered insecure, or the public email (google, yahoo etc)? I thought email IDs with oganizational domains are considered "secure" (as in, their recipients are legitimate)

Comment: @JENNY you should edit your question to indicate that you were hired in person.  Comments like these can easily be deleted, and will leave people to think that it was a scam hiring.

Comment: "over a insecure channel " if you are sending it to a scammer directly, it makes little difference whether the channel is secure or not.

Comment: @Kevin I-9 verification must be done by inspecting documents in person or, if certain conditions are met, via live video. If they're asking for just the form, it's likely to be a scam.

Comment: @user71659: I guarantee there is some manager, somewhere out there, who has entirely failed to read and/or understand the form, and checked a box saying that they "saw a document in person" even though they did not. Yes, that is illegal and stupid, but it probably has happened at some point.

Comment: @JENNY, I am confused. You said you got hired in person, but you have accepted this answer. So, was it a scam or not?

Answer (score 10):

First thing first, be very cautious about whom you hand out the ID and SSN and other PII (Personal Identifiable Information).

If you have received and sent the communication in an official channel (company mail ID, for example), then mostly you should be OK. Otherwise, politely request them to send the requirement via an official channel, and supply the information in a way that has traces (like, uploading information to a company portal).

Of course, if you have started working already, this should not matter much, but before joining, practice some caution.

That said, to answer your "question" - there's no harm in following up, get in touch with them and check whether they have received the information you shared and whether they'd need something more from you. Don't forget to thank them in the end.

Comment: You should not be sending social security information via email, whether it's from the company or not. This is not a secure channel.

Comment: @coppereyecat OK, i'm listening. What are some examples of a secure channel where PII can be transferred without submitting the copies in-person?

Comment: If working for an in-person employer, I would only present them in person. However, I have been working remote for a few years and have had to submit online. This is typically done through a secure portal on the company's website or their payroll service's. Still a bit nervewracking to do so tbh.

Answer (score 6):

If she still needs it, she'll get back to you, either before or after you show up on your first day.

How sure are you that you're actually hired? Do you have a start, a specific salary, work hours, information about benefits if any, or any of the other stuff that normally accompanies being hired?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a mutually signed work contract in your hands?

No?

...looks you have learned something new again.

(P.s. the point, where you can stop applying for jobs, happens with that you meet the Boss face to face, and you both sign the contract with your hands.)

Comment: (Now that electronic signatures start to becoming legally binding and common, possibly there is the time of some... update to this rule, but the essence remains always the same.)

Answer (score -1):

> do I message again or move on?

Yes, continue to reach out to them. You have provided them your email and SSN. Keep trying to reach them.

Yes, continue to pursue other options. Keep searching, keep applying, keep interviewing. You do this in case something that appears solid falls apart. You don't want to realize in a few weeks, after you have paused your search, that the job won't be starting anytime soon.

Comment: *Keep searching* isn't wrong. **Put on some clothes and go there.** And if you can't find it, then you're in trouble.